# Regex to convert CamelCase to snake case in Redshift

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-redshift

I am trying to convert CamelCase to either snake case or separated by a delimiter using `regex` in SQL (AWS Redshift). So something like

`regexp_replace(MyString, '([A-Z]+)', '-$1')`

except I need to specify not at the beginning of the string. Right now,

`MyString` -> `-my-string` instead of `my-string`.

How do I do this?

Comment: This fails for strings in allcaps but totally works for the question I asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match and capture any char before the uppercase letters, and restore it using another backreference in the replacement pattern:

```
regexp_replace(MyString, '(.)([A-Z]+)', '$1-$2')
                          ^^^            ^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SAUGCD/1).

I understand you already `LOWER` the result after the regex replacement.